# Get path to iOS application based on name or bundle identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

Is there an easier way to get the path to an iOS application, than searching `/var/mobile/Applications`?

I know both the name and the bundle identifier, however the path is not consistent on different iOS devices.

This is for use in a jailbreak tweak, so I can use PrivateFrameworks and other code not allowed by Apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running code that executes in Springboard, this should be fairly simple. Get `SBApplicationController`'s `sharedInstance`, then get the `SBApplication` you're looking for with the `applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:` method (or using whatever method you choose). The `SBApplication` class contains properties for `path`, `containerPath`, and `bundle` (among many others), one of which should be what you're looking for. I haven't tried this myself, so I can't guarantee it'll work, but based on a quick glance at the Springboard header files (you can take a look [here](https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/tree/master/include/SpringBoard), or dump the header files yourself), it should work.

On the other hand, if you're not running from Springboard (ie. if you're making an actual App Store-style application), then you may be out of luck. You could look into inter-process communication with Springboard and see if something can be done there, but it'd probably be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

If running in an app, you can define:

```
extern NSString* SBSCopyBundlePathForDisplayIdentifier(NSString* bundleId);
```

and link to the `SpringboardServices` framework.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use the library [AppList](https://github.com/rpetrich/AppList) and then it's:

```
ALApplicationList *al = [ALApplicationList sharedApplicationList];
NSString *appPath = [al valueForKey:@"path" forDisplayIdentifier:bundleID];
```

In this case it's doing what *Andrew R.* mentions in his answer for you. (I assume the same requirements are necessary, i.e. must be running from Springboard.)

Update: This no longer seems to be working on iOS 11.